# Unrecognized Property in fetching data from JSONObject in Jersey web service

Tags: json, web-services, jersey, jackson, jax-rs

I need to convert a certain JSON string to a Java object. I am using Jackson for JSON handling.
Here is my Java class:

```
public class RequestClass {

    String email_id;
    String password;

    public String getEmailId() {
        return email_id;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){

        return email_id+" "+password;
    }
}
```

Here is the web service code:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/dbconnect3")
public String connectToDbTest3(RequestClass rc) {
    System.out.println("connectToDbTest3");
    String email_id = rc.getEmailId();
    String password = rc.getPassword();
    System.out.println(email_id + " " + password);
}
```

This throws exception `UnrecognizedPropertyException` with message `"Unrecognized field "email_id" (Class jaxrs.RequestClass), not marked as ignorable"`.

In case i am not using the annotation `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` in my Java class, the output I am getting on line 09 is:

```
null myPassword
```

So I don't want to ignore Unrecognized field instead I want to get the value of `email_id`.

Please tell why It shows `email_id` as Unrecognized field while password is fetched successfully.

Comment: It should be @JsonProperty("email_id") answer updated

Answer (score 2):

Just add [`@JsonProperty("email_id")`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) before the `getEmailId()` like given below:

```
@JsonProperty("email_id")
public String getEmailId() {
   return email_id;
}
```